# How to find the text in a table row/table data

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to change the color of the text in table row with the class '24hrs'. I used jquery to find the text, but i just can't figure it out.

This is the table i'm working with

```
            <table class="table" id="characters-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Logo</th>
                    <th>Abbreviation</th>
                    <th>Coin</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Market Cap</th>
                    <th>24hr</th>
                    <th>More info</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template id="all-characters-template">
                    {{#Data}}
                    <tr>
                        <td><img class="img-coin" src="https://www.cryptocompare.com{{CoinInfo.ImageUrl}}"/></td>
                        <td class="character-id">{{CoinInfo.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{CoinInfo.FullName}}</td>
                        <td>{{DISPLAY.EUR.PRICE}}</td>
                        <td>{{RAW.EUR.MKTCAP}}</td>
                        <td class="24hrs">{{DISPLAY.EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}}</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-info character-info-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">More Info</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/Data}}
                </template>
```

I tried this, but it coudln't find anything

```
console.log($("#all-characters-template").closest("tr").find(".24hrs").text());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the *rendered* HTML, there won't be a element with id `all-characters-template` as that's your templating engine.    Check `console.log($("#all-characters-template").length)` - if it's `0` then the rest won't give anything.

Comment: You should probably just use CSS for this anyway.

Comment: Re:comment above - your question asks to find the text, but you also ask to change the colour - you don't need to find the text to change the colour:  `$(".24hrs").css("background-color", "red");` (or just in your css) (note answer below where ".24hrs" is not valid).  Why do you need to find the text?

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried console.log($("#all-characters-template").length), it gave back 24, but i still can't change the color

Comment: Change class name from `24hrs` to `hrs24` in the html and your code and try again

Comment: Yes i changed it to .hours already, but still nothing

Comment: @freedomn-m and i also need to find the text, because i want to check if the number is higher or lower than 0

Comment: Ah - change colour based on text.  Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

CSS classnames cannot start with a number.

See: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

Answer (score 0):

As already commented you try to use the id of your template engine, not of your rendered html element. So try this instead:

```
$('#characters-table tbody .24hrs').css('color', 'red');
```